# Issue with setAsciiStream method?

Tags: java, teradata

I read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setAsciiStream%28int,%20java.io.InputStream%29) . As far as I understand `setAsciiStream` takes only two arguments.

However in the [official java snippet](http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/samp/T20208JD.java.txt) one can find the following:

```
pstmtFld.setAsciiStream(1, dataStream, -1);
 pstmtFld.executeUpdate();
```

I am confused. What does the `setAsciiStream` exactly do, and especially what is the third argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong javadoc:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setAsciiStream(int,%20java.io.InputStream,%20long)

setAsciiStream(int parameterIndex,
                    InputStream x,
                    long length)
                    throws SQLException
Sets the designated parameter to the given input stream, which will have the specified number of bytes. When a very large ASCII value is input to a LONGVARCHAR parameter, it may be more practical to send it via a java.io.InputStream. Data will be read from the stream as needed until end-of-file is reached. The JDBC driver will do any necessary conversion from ASCII to the database char format.
Note: This stream object can either be a standard Java stream object or your own subclass that implements the standard interface.

There's also one with an int for length:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setAsciiStream(int,%20java.io.InputStream,%20int)

Comment: Thank you, where can i find the right documentation. I am still confused a little

Comment: I linked to it, but it looks like SO ate it.  Gimme a sec

Answer (score 1):

The method it uses is:

[setAsciiStream(int parameterIndex,
                  InputStream x,
                  int length)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setAsciiStream%28int,%20java.io.InputStream,%20int%29)

Which takes a `length` argument. Chances are, -1 means any amount.